# C++ Thread local storage - same name used in different compilation units

Tags: c++, thread-specific-storage

Assume we have the following code in some compilation unit that eventually is compiled to a shared lib on Linux (g++ 4.9)

```
namespace A {
    class B {
       static __thread MyObj *myobj;
    };
}
```

So this is compiled into .so and it does not export this symbol (using visibility hidden).

Now, a specific app has the same piece of code that is being used. I.e. same cpp compilation unit is linked with this app, that also access the above shared lib.

Question - are these 2 myobj instances resides in 2 different addresses in TLS? I assume yes but I'm seeing issues that might be related to the above configuration.

Comment: Show a complete example.  Is the client code including the above in a header?

Comment: Why are using `__thread` instead of `thread_local`?

Comment: @stark yes. It does.

Comment: @vtt you are correct but the code is a 3rd party one. not mine.